# Why is Docker suddenly trying to open docker-entrypoint.sh?

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu

I have dockerised a Node.js app for my Ubuntu server. The Dockerfile is incredibly simple, and had been working fine. Suddenly, on my Ubuntu server, I'm now seeing this error:

```
sudo docker run -p 80:8080 username/test:test
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:12

# Create the app directory
WORKDIR /Tap2Tap/TapServer

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

There is no reference to this docker-entrypoint.sh and I don't know why it seems to have spontaneously stopped working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Best,
Peter

package.json file is:

```
{
    "name": "Tap2Tap",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^3.22.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "mqtt": "^4.0.1",
    "pg": "^8.0.3",
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.4.2"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run with privileged user (root)? You are trying to bind a privileged port (80) without sudo permission.

Comment: Ah apologies. the command is run with sudo... I'll edit the question!

Comment: Can you post full file in your `npm start` alias, in your package.json?

Comment: I have no idea what the reason is, but I completely wiped Docker from the server and reinstalled it. Now it works fine. Curious.